# How to alert a selected text inside kendo editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

How to alert a selected text inside kendo editor?
I tried below code

```
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
<script>
$("#editor").kendoEditor();
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
var html = editor.getSelection();
</script>
```

But it gives me error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'getSelection' in undefined`

Then my textarea is

```
 <textarea id="editor" kendo-editor k-ng-model="html"></textarea>


<script>
    var textarea = $("#editor");
    textarea.kendoEditor({ value: "Hello, how are you doing !" });
    var editor = textarea.data("kendoEditor");
    $('#buttonB').click(function () {

        alert(textarea);
        alert(editor.getSelection());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected value of Kendo UI Editor content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252573/how-to-get-selected-value-of-kendo-ui-editor-content)

Comment: have you tried putting the code on `$(document).ready` function?

Answer (score 0):

Using what I saw in Kendo documentation (https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/events), adding a *select* property assigned to a function triggered by the select event:

```
<script>
    var textarea = $("#editor");
    textarea.kendoEditor({ 
        value: "Hello, how are you doing !",
        select: onSelect
    });
    var editor = textarea.data("kendoEditor");

    function onSelect() {
        alert(editor.getSelection());
    }

    $('#buttonB').click(function () {

        alert(textarea);
        alert(editor.getSelection());
    });
</script>
```